# MySQL division equivalent not working

Tags: mysql, database, relational-algebra, relational-division

I'm trying to implement the equivalence of relational algebra's division in MySQL.

```
create table tham_gia(
  MaNV int unsigned not null ,
  MaDA int unsigned not null ,
  So_Gio int unsigned not null default 0,
  primary key (MaNV, MaDA)
);
```

Now I want to find which `MaNV` is in all of `MaDA` available on the table. This requires a division, which is not supported, so I plan to use the equivalence of it using 5 primitive operations in relational algebra, as outlined here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29
 Division (÷)

> The division is a binary operation that is written as `R ÷ S`. The result consists of the restrictions of tuples in `R` to the
>   attribute names unique to `R`, i.e., in the header of `R` but not in
>   the header of `S`, for which it holds that all their combinations with
>   tuples in `S` are present in `R`.

For an example see the tables Completed, DBProject and their division:

```
Completed Student   Task
Fred    Database1
Fred    Database2
Fred    Compiler1
Eugene  Database1
Eugene  Compiler1
Sarah   Database1
Sarah   Database2

DBProject Task
Database1
Database2

Completed ÷ DBProject Student
Fred
Sarah

If DBProject contains all the tasks of the Database project, then the result of the division above contains exactly the students who have completed both of the tasks in the Database project.

More formally the semantics of the division is defined as follows:

    R ÷ S = { t[a1,...,an] : t \in R \wedge \foralls \in S ( (t[a1,...,an] \cup s) \in R) }

where {a1,...,an} is the set of attribute names unique to R and t[a1,...,an] is the restriction of t to this set. It is usually required that the attribute names in the header of S are a subset of those of R because otherwise the result of the operation will always be empty.

The simulation of the division with the basic operations is as follows. We assume that a1,...,an are the attribute names unique to R and b1,...,bm are the attribute names of S. In the first step we project R on its unique attribute names and construct all combinations with tuples in S:

    T := πa1,...,an(R) × S

In the prior example, T would represent a table such that every Student (because Student is the unique key / attribute of the Completed table) is combined with every given Task. So Eugene, for instance, would have two rows, Eugene -> Database1 and Eugene -> Database2 in T.

In the next step we subtract R from T relation:

    U := T − R

Note that in U we have the possible combinations that "could have" been in R, but weren't. So if we now take the projection on the attribute names unique to R then we have the restrictions of the tuples in R for which not all combinations with tuples in S were present in R:

    V := πa1,...,an(U)

So what remains to be done is take the projection of R on its unique attribute names and subtract those in V:

    W := πa1,...,an(R) − V
```

Here is my code:

```
select MaNV as EmpCode1
from tham_gia 
where EmpCode1 not in(
    select MaNV as EmpCode  
    from (  
        select MaNV as ECode, MaDA as PrCode
        from (
            select MaNV as E1Code
            from tham_gia) 
        cross join (
            select MaDA as Pr1Code
            from tham_gia)

        where ECode, PrCode not in(
            select MaNV as E2Code, MaDA as Pr2Code
            from tham_gia) 
        )  
    ) ;
```

But it didn' work! Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: The question might be precise enough to answer, but seems pretty abstract. Would you please provide a few real data examples (records in your table and expected result)?

Comment: Also, it's unclear how MaNV relates to MaDA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, tham_gia is kind of an alias for Participate, MaNV for EmpCode and MaDA for PrjCode(Project Code). Basically what i want is to find all Employees who participates in all available projects in Participate (sorry for the strange alias, guys!)
I just found the answer from this link: 
https://faculty.utpa.edu/lianx/old_courses/CSCI4333_2014fall/MySQL-set-operators.pdf
Basically it used the same principle as I did, but much less obvious (it has a table "a" with column "x,y", a table "b" with column "x", it wishes to divide a by b):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.y AS y 
FROM c c1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT d.x FROM d  
  WHERE d.x NOT IN (SELECT c2.x FROM c c2 WHERE c2.y = c1.y));
```

Based on this, I made some modifications:

```
select Par1.EmpCode
from Participate as Par1
where not exists (
    select Par2.PrjCode
    from Participate as Par2
    where Par2.PrjCode not in (
        select Par3.PrjCode
        from Participate as Par3
        where Par3.EmpCode = Par1.EmpCode));
```

And it worked! Thanks anyway :)